# How can I simulate window.focus() with react testing-library?

Tags: react-testing-library, testing-library, user-event

I've been doing a lot of research, and I can't find a way to successfully simulate a window focus event.

I looked through "testing-library/user-event" and still can't find a way to do this.

In my component, we have `window.addEventListener('focus', doSomething);` but this is never getting invoked via the test runner.

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you share how you add the event listener?

Answer (score 1):

I have verified that `fireEvent.focus(window);` does actually trigger the handler, and that the callback just isn't behaving as expected.

Comment: `fireEvent.focus(window);` worked for me, my test coverage just went up!